# Bundling an (unmanaged, pre-compiled) executable with my output?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, bundle

I'm writing a library that uses a command-line tool to prepare the environment. I know I could distribute them together, but the library functions as a module which the user will be moving around. I can foresee a lot of support issues being caused by people deleting the tool that they don't recognise, or failing to extract / copy it in the first place.

Hence my question:

**Can I bundle an (unmanaged, pre-compiled) executable inside a class library?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can add it as a resource to your assembly, just like an image. When you need to use it, you can write it to a temporary folder on the disk and execute it from there.